# VB.NET Mobile Application Settings

Tags: windows, vb.net, settings.settings

I've created an application that stores username and password information, inserted by the user, using the Application Settings. This application is suppose to be mobile, I mean, you should be able to carry it from one computer to other without losing information. But I've notice that when I change the folder the app is in, all settings are lost. I've run the internet in search for answers, but all I've found is storing the data in XML files.

Comment: try storing them as embedded resources, that should make it more portable.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add in the question that these information are suppose to be requested to the user. You're suppose to input the username and the password, and then store them in the application.
I've already edited the question...

Comment: You really should show some code so we can get a better handle on what you're doing.  If I'm not mistaken, the setting are stored in a different file and included when the app is installed.  You may have to resort to using the Publish option.

Comment: It would imply sending you the whole project. But the most important part relies on code such as 'My.Settings.Username = Textbox1.Text' for example. The user would isert it's username, and the app would store it. And it was supose to carry that information whenever I moved the application from folder to folder.
I've been reading Microsoft MSDN's webpage for information, and in fact settings are stored in a XML file related to the application. But I wonder where is it being saved and why doesn't it load up in different folders in the same machine...

Comment: It's just like any other software you install, to move the app you have to re-install.  One option that might work is use shortcuts to the app instead of moving it.

Comment: I've made my mind, and I've decided not to make it portable. Still, I'll include another application, that will be built into the main application to 'compress' all the files and save it, for example, in a pen drive. Then another application will uncompress the files, and return it to it's normal state.
thanks for your help! :)